# how to get child user control by id from a parent panel user control?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

for eg. my code is

```
void abc(usercontrolclass ucc)
{
   this.panel.Controls.Add(ucc);
}

void def()
{
  usercontrolclass ucc1 = this.panel.Controls.GetChildUserControl(ucc);

}
```

Note "GetChildUserControl" is not a valid function what i require is a method or 
      function which i can use to get ucc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Set user controls `tag` property.

2 - Add user control to its parent.

3 - Get user control by its `Tag` property from parent by iterating [`Control.Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx).

Your code should be like this:

```
void AddControl(UserControl control, int id)
{
    control.Tag = id;
    this.panel.Controls.Add(control);
}

UserControl GetControl(int id)
{
    foreach (Control control in this.panel.Controls)
    {
        if (id == (int) control.Tag)
            return (UserControl) control;
    }
    return null;
}

// or using LINQ
UserControl GetControl(int id)
{
    return Controls.Cast<UserControl>()
                   .FirstOrDefault(control => id == (int) control.Tag);
}
```

Comment: Cant i do this without looping through each control?

Answer (score 0):

A user control is also 'just' a control, so it has a Controls property with the child controls. Use it.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx).