# Access controls not properties in XAML User Control

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-store-apps

I already know how to compose User Control and access inner control properties with Dependency Properties in XAML User Control.

My question is, how to access a control itself inside of User Control.
For example,

**User Control: TbCanvas.xaml**

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Sample.Control.TbCanvas"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400"
x:Name="root">
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="imageMain" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I'd like to use it in some `Page` that has above User Control as below.

**SomePage.xaml.cs**

```
this.tbCanvas.imageMain.Source = "some_path";
```

Of course, the `Source` can be given as `Dependency Property` with `Binding`, but I sometimes need to access inner controls because every property of controls are not entirely bindable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these links

[C# usercontrol how to access all child controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346533/c-sharp-usercontrol-how-to-access-all-child-controls)

[how to get child user control by id from a parent panel user control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734148/how-to-get-child-user-control-by-id-from-a-parent-panel-user-control)

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/141469/how-to-access-child-control-of-a-user-control

Comment: Thanks. first link helps me. so simple but I didn't imagine.